# How to type a ViewPage as IList

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This question is for someone who has read Professional ASP.NET MVC 1.0 (Scott Gu..) Chapter 7 AJAX. On page 286 they list the contents of the partial but do not show how to type it as IList

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to type it as:  `ViewPage<IList<MyCustomClass>>`

Comment: So at the top of the partial view like this:

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IList<MyCustomClass>>" %>

Comment: If you do it this way remember to put System.Collections.Generic in the namespaces section of your web.config. Or you could type it all out Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<System.Collections.Generic.IList<MyCustomClass>>"